# Flexbox doesn't take full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i'm trying to make a top bar with flexbox, i want to have an icon on the top-left part of the site and a nav on the right side. So i write this in css:

```
.barra {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.barra a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

But the bar only took half the width.

The HTML looks like this

```
<body>
    <div class=barra>
        <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>
        <nav class=navegacion>
            <a href="#">Productos<a>
            <a href="#">Servicios<a>
            <a href="#">Contacto<a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried with "Width: 100%; in the .barra but it didn't do anything

I dont know what is wrong here, i would appreciate some help.
I'm using ruby on rails to make the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing closing tags for your anchors.

`<a>...</a>`

New markup:

```html
<div class=barra>
  <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>
  <nav class=navegacion>
    <a href="#">Productos</a>
    <a href="#">Servicios</a>
    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/koralarts/pen/wvaxERr

Comment: YES! Thank you! I Didn't realize i forgot the bar and i read it 200 times..

Answer (score 0):

Your example in fact does take the full width:

Using `border: 1px solid red` is a good way to debug these things.

Do you perhaps have other styles that apply to `.barra`?

```css
.barra {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.barra a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    <div class=barra>
        <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>
        <nav class=navegacion>
            <a href="#">Productos<a>
            <a href="#">Servicios<a>
            <a href="#">Contacto<a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right but this is maybe what you are looking for, I added flex display on the `<nav>` and `<i>`, the icon tag is not visible since you didn't include font-awesome style.

```css
.barra {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.barra nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    flex: 4;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 95%;
}

.barra i {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="barra">
        <i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>
        <nav class="navegacion">
            <a href="#">Productos</a>
            <a href="#">Servicios</a>
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your typos. You are not closing any anchor tag, but only creating `broken HTML`.

```css
.barra {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: yellow;
}
.barra a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
i {
 display: block;
}
nav {
  background: red;
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class=barra>
        <i class="fas fa-wifi">i</i>
        <nav class=navegacion>
            <a href="#">Productos</a>
            <a href="#">Servicios</a>
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have modified the **class names** .Please use proper names which should be related to it *semantically*.

Some **errors** are in the code

1.You forgot to quote the class names

```
<nav class=navegacion>
```

2. You forgot to close the tags properly.

Modified code

```css
.header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;

        background-color: black;
        color: whitesmoke;
      }

      .navigation a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: whitesmoke;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>repl.it</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <i class="fas fa-wifi">icon</i>
      <nav class="navigation">
        <a href="#">Productos</a>
        <a href="#">Servicios</a>
        <a href="#">Contacto</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```